# php file exists or not

Tags: php

I have the following code, what is the easiest way to check if $data has something in it?

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

$data = fread($handle, filesize($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']));
```

when I do

```
file_exists($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']
```

it prints out 1? does 1 mean exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in some languages 1 and 0 represent boolean values

`1` as `true`
`0` as `false`

```
if(1) {
 //do something
}
```

equal to

```
if(true) {
 //do something
}
```

Comment: Minor addition; they do not represent boolean values but rather get evaluated to boolean values. `true === 1` still evaluates to false where `true == 1` evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2):

`file_exists()` will return a boolean value, where 1 == TRUE and 0 == FALSE.

Typically you would use something like:

```
if (file_exists($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) {
  // success
}
else {
  // failure
}
```

Easier than `fopen()`, `fread()` is [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
if (file_exists($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) {
  $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);
  echo $data;
}
```

Comment: Actually cannot imagine a case when uploaded file couldn't exist (except if it hasn't been deleted explicitly in the same script few lines earlier) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It means that `file_exists()` function returned `true` which has been casted to 1. And yes - that means that file exists.

Comment: You could use `is_file()` too which won't give `TRUE` for a directory :)

Comment: @alex: yep, but it cannot be applied for cases like OP has (when we check if uploaded *file* exists) ;-P

Answer (score 0):

"file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance."

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
if(file_exists($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']))
   $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file_exists($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) {
    // file does exist... 
    // we can move it now.. or do some more "checking" on it.
} else {
    // file doesn't exist...
}
```

This here (file_exists()) will return a boolean value on whether or not the file DOES exist.

If it's true, and you output this.. it will be equal to one.  If it's false, it's "nothing" or 0.

Here is how booleans work... just for reference..

These are considered **false**

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

Every other value is considered **true**